# Don't know why my Jquery code is not working (works with CSS)

Tags: jquery, html, css, navigation

Hey ya'll been having this problem and it won't go away....

http://www.willruppelglass.com/

I have 3 menu items home, gallery and info. if you hover over gallery or info a submenu appears. However when I goto hover over the submenu it disappears right away :( I would like to able to hover over the sub menu and I dont know why this code is not working...

```
 $(".galleryNavToggle").on("mouseenter mouseleave", function(event){
    var headNavGal = $("#headerNavGallery");
    if(event.type === "mouseenter"){
      headNavGal.show();
    }else if(event.type ==="mouseleave" &&
             ((event.relatedTarget !== headNavGal[0] && $.inArray(event.relatedTarget, headNavGal.find("*")) <=0) ||
             $.inArray(event.relatedTarget, $(".galleryNavInfoToggle")) > 0)){
        headNavGal.hide();
    }
});
$("#headerNavGallery").on("mouseleave", function(event){
    var headNavGal = $(this);
    if(event.type ==="mouseleave"){
        headNavGal.hide();
    }
});


$(".galleryNavInfoToggle").on("mouseenter mouseleave", function(event){
    var headNavGal = $("#headerNavInfo");
    if(event.type === "mouseenter"){
      headNavGal.show();
    }else if(event.type ==="mouseleave" &&
             ((event.relatedTarget !== headNavGal[0] && $.inArray(event.relatedTarget, headNavGal.find("*")) <=0) ||
             $.inArray(event.relatedTarget, $(".galleryNavInfoToggle")) > 0)){
        headNavGal.hide();
    }
});
$("#headerNavInfo").on("mouseleave", function(event){
    var headNavGal = $(this);
    if(event.type ==="mouseleave"){
        headNavGal.hide();
    }
});
```

Here is my HTML

```
    <div class="headerWrapper">
    <div class="headerNav">
    <ul>
    <li><a href="index.php?action=view">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" class='galleryNavToggle'>Gallery</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" class='galleryNavInfoToggle'>Info</a></li>
    </ul>
    </div><!--headerNav-->
    </div><!--headerWrapper-->

<div class="contentWrapper">
<div class="content" id="content">
<div class="topContent">
<div class="headerNavGallery" id="headerNavGallery" style="display:none;">
<ul>
<li><a href="#">Categoies</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Products</a></li>
</ul>
</div><!--headerNavGallery-->

<div class="headerNavInfo" id="headerNavInfo" style="display:none;">
<ul>
<li><a href="#">William Ruppel</a></li>
<li><a href="#">CV</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Artist Bio</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Video</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
</ul>
</div><!--headerNavInfo-->
</div><!--topContent-->
</div><!--contentWrapper-->
```

Any help or a point in the right direction would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advanced,

- J

Comment: And yes they submenus need to be outside the headerWrapper

Comment: There's a fine line between asking someone for help in doing your job, and asking someone to do your job for you.  This question (which amounts to "please debug my code for me") feels like it's on the wrong side of that line.

Comment: I could have sum down the code and asked how to get something to work outside the div, but I am drawing a blank

Comment: i agree with machineghost, you need to isolate your problem and ask a specific technical question if you cannot solve it yourself. creating a simple jsfiddle demonstrating the bad behavior would be a good start.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you should do is completely remove your mouseleave event.  Instead on the mouseenter event hide both sub menus like so :

```
    $(".galleryNavToggle").on("mouseenter", function (event) {
        $('#headerNavGallery, #headerNavInfo').hide();
        $("#headerNavGallery").show();
    });

    $(".galleryNavInfoToggle").on("mouseenter", function (event) {
        $('#headerNavGallery, #headerNavInfo').hide();
        $("#headerNavInfo").show();
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the issue is happening because in order to mouse over the submenu, you have to mouse off of the trigger. This is firing the mouseleave event and causing the submenu to close.

For dropdown menus I like to put the submenu inside of the top level element rather than having them be two separate elements. That way when you hover the submenu your mouse is still technically inside the parent element that fires the events.

For example

```
<ul id="nav">
    <li id="gallery">
        Gallery
        <ul class="subnav">
            <li>Subnav 1</li>
            <li>Subnav 2</li>
            <li>Subnav 3</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li id="info">
        Info
        <ul class="subnav">
            <li>Subnav 1</li>
            <li>Subnav 2</li>
            <li>Subnav 3</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

So in your CSS you could have

```
.subnav {
    display: none;
}
```

And then in jQuery (or even in CSS) you can set the subnav to display block on mouseover. Because the subnav lives inside the menu item the mouseleave won't fire until you leave that area completely.